# Mocha testing broken after upgrade to Meteor 1.5.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, meteor, mocha.js

After upgrading to Meteor 1.5.1 from 1.4.4.2 I'm receiving this error when I run `meteor test` (while it ran fine).

**With a boilerplate scaffold after `meteor create`, the error I get is:**

```
TypeError: module1.exportDefault is not a function
W20170724-19:29:39.142(-7)? (STDERR)
W20170724-19:29:39.142(-7)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.practicalmeteor:mocha.meteor.src.setup.setupMochaClient.js (packages/practicalmeteor:mocha/meteor/src/setup/setupMochaClient.js:1:9)
W20170724-19:29:39.142(-7)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:333:9)
W20170724-19:29:39.143(-7)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:228:16)
W20170724-19:29:39.143(-7)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.practicalmeteor:mocha.meteor.src.setup.index.js (packages/practicalmeteor:mocha/meteor/src/setup/index.js:1:150)
W20170724-19:29:39.143(-7)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:333:9)
W20170724-19:29:39.144(-7)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:228:16)
W20170724-19:29:39.144(-7)? (STDERR)     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.practicalmeteor:mocha.meteor.src.index.js (packages/practicalmeteor:mocha/meteor/src/index.js:1:431)
W20170724-19:29:39.144(-7)? (STDERR)     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:333:9)
W20170724-19:29:39.145(-7)? (STDERR)     at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:228:16)
W20170724-19:29:39.145(-7)? (STDERR)     at /private/var/folders/wz/73gq7k591wjbmk5zjf_1h5bnlwwdyw/T/meteor-test-runvsqg43/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/practicalmeteor_mocha.js:8141:15
```

Check out the gist for [PACKAGES, METEOR_LIST, UPGRADE LOG, ERROR, PACKAGE.JSON](https://gist.github.com/Falieson/8d86cf693ed68d3672bb4e19d586b0f4)

I've tried to figure out what package is causing the issue, but no luck so far. I appreciate any of your guidance in debugging or solution if you've figured this out already!

Thanks. :)

Comment: C'mon meteorites, where are you on this?

Comment: Any update on this @toszter?